# jQuery update breaks plugin functions

Tags: jquery

i routinely use some basic plugins, like [cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) for image cycling, and some of the modal plugins like colorbox.

i always link to jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
```

but since the latest version a couple of weeks ago - all my scripts have stopped working. i have had to manually link to 1.7.2 or 1.8 for them to work.

any idea what happened?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check for any JavaScript errors within your site when using jQuery version 1.9.

Because you are using this **googleapi** content delivery network, it automatically picks the latest version of jQuery available. With jQuery 1.9 there were a lot of changes and events/functions were removed which will cause some plugins/old code to break.

There is a high chance a 3rd party plugin is going to be using the `live()` event handler which has now been removed in version 1.9.

Have a read here to see what has changed. [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Google CDN to retrieve your jQuery. This is actually correct, but you have to know which version you're including. Check out the version numbers and validate the differences:

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

Get's the latest v1.x.x version of jQuery

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js
```

Get's the latest v1.8.x version of jQuery

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
```

Get's a specific version: v1.9.0 in this case.

If you don't want your plugins to break in the future, I would suggest you to go with the jQuery version that works, instead of "dynamically" let Google update them (or check the plugin for updates to check if they updated to the latest version of jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Tim, 1.9.0 has some major changes  - the following article on SitePoint is worth a read on why and how to track and fix problems:

http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-19-whats-new/

You can use google to link to jQuery 1.8.1 (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js)